# How to retrieve JSON data from array of JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Writing a JS code to loop over an array and get the values. Getting value as `object` on iterating through array.

Here is the actual JSON that's to be looped over.

```
[ { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' } ]
```

Sample code to iterate over array:

```js
var data = [ { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' } ]



function newX(data) {
    console.log(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
    }
}
newX(data);
```

Output:

```
{"sum":"[object Object]","count":"[object Object]"}
{"sum":"[object Object]","count":"[object Object]"}
{"sum":"[object Object]","count":"[object Object]"}
{"sum":"[object Object]","count":"[object Object]"}
{"sum":"[object Object]","count":"[object Object]"}
{"sum":"[object Object]","count":"[object Object]"}
{"sum":"[object Object]","count":"[object Object]"}
```

but here need to see the actual values.

please let me know on how can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you stingifying?

Comment: and it looks like something went bad while creating the JSON

Comment: Hi @ParnabSanyal when I did a console.log(typeof data), it was showing me type as object :(

Comment: Your input does not contain the data - from a string of `'[object Object]'`, you cannot retrieve anything more meaningful. Better to fix the input.

Comment: Agreed with @CertainPerformance

Comment: where does the json com from? Do you build it yourself?

Comment: Those are JavaScript objects (and arrays), not JSON.

Comment: it's like you first name a child 'name' then asking why your name is 'name'. like `var name = 'my name';` and on `console.log(name)` i need to see `Navin` however there's something wrong with javascript and output is  `my name`. You assigned `var sum = '[object Object]'` so you will get output same as input. If need actual object assign actual object `var sum = {a: 4, b: 3, s: 7}` now you will get object.

Comment: You're giving instructions to print something and the output is exactly what you have instructed. There is nothing wrong with the output. Please cross-check your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The mistake really just is calling .log() on an jsObject and not it's properties. console.log(data[i]**.sum**) is the only thing you have to change :D

The function toString on an object outputs [object Object] (if it's a plain object), so you probably tried to output an object without any of it's properties, fix that and your console.log will work :)

```js
var data = [ { sum: 'xx', count: 'yy' },
  { sum: 'xy', count: 'yx' }]



function newX(data) {
    console.log(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log("sum: " + data[i].sum + "\ncount: " + data[i].count); 
    }
}
newX(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `JSON.stringify`. If you want to get a value from an object you need to use the '.' (dot) property accessors, you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
var data = [ { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' },
  { sum: '[object Object]', count: '[object Object]' } ]



function newX(data) {
    console.log(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log('sum = '+data[i].sum + '  count = '+data[i].count);
    }
}
newX(data);
```